# Change in graphic style - ConvexHull

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions

I use this code to find the `ConvexHull` for some points:

```
pts2 = {{2, 1}, {5, 0}, {7, 0}, {9, 5}, {6, 8}, {0, 6}, {0, 4}};
Show[ConvexHullMesh[pts2, GridLines -> Automatic], Axes -> True]
```

the result is this pic:

[image]

I need the result like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

*(included more style specifications as requested in the comments)*

You can use [`BaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseStyle) to control the appearance of the convex hull, and you can extract the coordinates of a mesh by using `mesh["Coordinates"]`. Finally, [`Arrowheads`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrowheads) can be used to style the axes:

```
pts2={{2,1},{5,0},{7,0},{9,5},{6,8},{0,6},{0,4}};

mesh = ConvexHullMesh[
    pts2,
    BaseStyle->{FrontFaceColor->None,EdgeColor->Black,FrontFaceOpacity->0}
];
Show[
    mesh,
    Graphics[{PointSize[Large],Point[mesh["Coordinates"]]}],
    GridLines->Automatic,
    Axes->True,
    AxesStyle->Arrowheads[{0.0,0.05}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Carl Woll   How can I show the point in the vertex and change the lines color to be Black, also How to add the narrows on x-axes

Answer (score 3):

Another way is with [`MeshCellStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCellStyle.html).

```
pts2 = {{2, 1}, {5, 0}, {7, 0}, {9, 5}, {6, 8}, {0, 6}, {0, 4}};

ConvexHullMesh[pts2, 
  Axes -> True, 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}], 
  GridLines -> Automatic, 
  MeshCellStyle -> {0 -> {PointSize[Large], Opacity[1], Black}, 
    1 -> {Thick, Black}, 2 -> None}
]
```

[image]

For whatever reason, the setting `2 -> None` is influencing the vertices. This is why I manually set `Opacity[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approximate facsimile:

```
ch = MeshPrimitives[ConvexHullMesh[pts2], 2];
bb = BoundingRegion[pts2];
cent = Mean[pts2];

Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Directive[Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[1]]], FaceForm[], bb},
          {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], ch},
          {AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[pts2]},
          {Text[Style["Γ", FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14], cent],
           Text[TraditionalForm[Subscript["O", Row[{0, 0}]]], {0, 0}, {1.2, 1.2}],
           Text[TraditionalForm[Subscript["O", Row[{∞, ∞}]]], Last[bb], -{1.2, 1.2}]},
          {MapIndexed[Text[Subscript["γ", #2[[1]]], cent + 0.9 (Mean[#] - cent)] &, 
                      Partition[ch[[1, 1]], 2, 1, 1]]}},
         Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {Style["μ", Medium], Style["ν", Medium]}, 
         AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0., 0.05}],
         GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dotted, Opacity[1/4]],
         Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False, "GridLinesInFront" -> False},
         PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1],
         Ticks -> {{{bb[[2, 1]], Subscript["O", Row[{∞, 0}]]}},
                   {{bb[[2, 2]], Subscript["O", Row[{0, ∞}]]}}}]
```

[image: figure]

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
pts2 = {{2, 1}, {5, 0}, {7, 0}, {9, 5}, {6, 8}, {0, 6}, {0, 4}};

chm = ConvexHullMesh[pts2];
chmlines = MeshPrimitives[chm, 1];
chmpts = Sequence @@@ MeshPrimitives[chm, 0];
axeslabels = Style[#, Bold, 14] & /@ {"\[Mu]", "\[Nu]"};
corner = {Max@chmpts[[All, 1]], Max@chmpts[[All, 2]]};
chmScaled = RegionResize[chm, 8];
labelpts = Midpoint /@ MeshPrimitives[chmScaled, 1];
labelNames = Array[Subscript[\[Gamma], #] &, 7];
bboxcorners = MapThread[Text[Style[#1, 14], #2, #3] &,
   {{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(O\), \(00\)]\)", 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(O\), \(\[Infinity]0\)]\)", 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(O\), \(\[Infinity]\[Infinity]\)]\)", 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(O\), \(0  \[Infinity]\)]\)"}
    , Sequence @@@ MeshPrimitives[BoundingRegion[chmpts], 0]
    , {{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, 0}}
    }
   ];
labels = MapThread[
   Text[Style[#1, 12, FontFamily -> "Euclid Fraktur"], #2] &
   , {labelNames, labelpts}
   ];

Graphics[{
  {Black, AbsoluteThickness[2], chmlines}
  (*,{FaceForm[],EdgeForm[{Dashed,AbsoluteThickness[2]}]
  ,BoundingRegion[chmpts]}*)
  , {Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[2], 
   Line[{corner, {0, corner . {0, 1}}}]}
  , {Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[2], 
   Line[{corner, {corner . {1, 0}, 0}}]}
  , {AbsolutePointSize[8], Point@chmpts}
  , labels
  , {Text[Style["\[CapitalGamma]", 16, FontFamily -> "Euclid Fraktur"]
    , RegionCentroid@chm]}
  , bboxcorners
  , {FaceForm[Opacity[0.2, Green]]
   , Polygon@(Sequence @@@ MeshPrimitives[chmScaled, 0])}
  }
 , GridLines -> {Range[10], Range[10]}
 , GridLinesStyle -> {{Gray, Dotted}, {Gray, Dotted}}
 , Axes -> True
 , AxesStyle -> Directive[{Black, Arrowheads[0.04]}]
 , AxesLabel -> axeslabels
 , PlotRange -> {{-1, 10}, {-1, 9.2}}
 , Ticks -> {{1, 2}, {1, 2}}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    Graphics[Line /@ Partition[AppendTo[pts2, First[pts2]], 2, 1],
GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListPlot[AppendTo[pts2, First[pts2]], PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
 Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, 
 GridLines -> {Range[0, 10, 0.5], Range[0, 10, 0.5]}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dotted], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}]]
```

[image]